# What is the time complexity of my code?

Tags: javascript, time-complexity, big-o

So I just started studying the Big O notation on my own. I thought I had understood the basics till I wrote a function to check for prime numbers and tried to figure out its time complexity. Here's the code:

```
function isPrime(num){
    if (num === 1 || num%1 !== 0){ //Checks if num is 1 or decimal
        return false;
    }
    else{ 
        for (var i = 2; i < num; i++) {
            if (num%i === 0 && i!== 1){ //Checks if any numbers from 2 to are divisible by num
                return false
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}

console.log(isPrime(6));
```

First thing that confused me is whether multiple conditions inside an if statement make any difference or it is just counted once? And then notice I have **three** return statements. Does that mean I have to include that last line of code where I pass a number to the function to evaluate its time-complexity? Or can I do it without a passed value and calculate for different cases?

Comment: Make your title actually describe your problem or question.

Comment: @takendarkk Thanks for pointing that out. It's my first time posting and I had forgotten to edit my title draft. Hope this makes it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

```
function isPrime(n){
    if (n === 1 || n%1 !== 0){ //Checks if num is 1 or decimal
        return false;
    }
    for (var i = 2; i < n; i++) {
        if (n%i === 0){
            return false
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

I have made some small refactoring which doesn't change the complexity but makes the code more readable for struggling with Big-O.

So for `n > 1`, n : orime, the number of operations is:

[image]

So the complexity of your algorithm is `O(n)`.

Comment: This doesn't take into account the time complexity of the `%` operation